# Java Game Optimizing

Tags: java, optimization

I'm trying to optimize my game. I've got object Handler that goes trought all objects and then render and tick them. If I have lot of objects in game game lags or don't start. Could you please help me? public class Handler {

```
public LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();

private GameObject tempObject;

private Camera cam;

public Handler(Camera cam) {
    this.cam = cam;
}

public void tick() {

    for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
        tempObject = object.get(i);

        tempObject.tick(object);

    }

}

public void render(Graphics g) {

    for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
        tempObject = object.get(i);

        tempObject.render(g);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First tip, don't use a linked list. At least not in this way. Use an ArrayList instead. If you absolutely have to use a linked list use an iterator.

Secondly it's probably a good idea to cull stuff on your screen. That should get you going for a while. Although I am willing to bet there are performance issues elsewhere as well.